# This error: "An error occurred while saving the attribute set 'happens when I try to save an existing attribute group

Tags: magento-1.7

The same installation of magento works on my localhost. But now, the online version is giving this error.
I created new attributes and when I try to add them to a group of attributes and press the button 'Save group attributes', just get the error "An error occurred while saving the attribute set."

After disable and clear the cache of magento, delete the contents of var/cache and var/seasson, the error persists.

I look at the source code file in **app\code\core\Mage\Adminhtml\controllers\Catalog\Product\SetController.php** and **saveAction()** method noticed that the line **`$data = Mage::helper('core')->jsonDecode($this->getRequest()->getPost('data'));`** seems to be the problem, because it is returning an empty array. (line with red rectangle in the image below). causing the exception represented by the green rectangle in the image below.

No error log is being generated, and am using the 1.6.0.0 version of magento.
[image: get_Post return empty]

Comment: I created attributes earlier but now it gives error as "Attribute with the same code already exists." And te attribute gets added, but Based On is blank and cant be saved if edited. Please assist, i tried flushing, disabling cache etc, no help on that part.

Comment: Vaibhav, I'm getting the same error, and not found any solution. Have you found a solution for the issue? Regards,

Answer (score 1):

I also had this issue at one point and it was caused by the `json_decode` PHP function, which was returning an empty array.

You could try using the Zend JSON decoder instead of magento's core helper.

```
Zend_Json_Decoder::decode($encodedValue, Zend_Json::TYPE_ARRAY);
```

When calling `Mage::helper('core')->jsonDecode()` the function calls `Zend_Json::decode` which checks if PHP function `json_decode` exists. If it's there, it will use that, otherwise it uses the Zend decode function

```
public static function decode($encodedValue, $objectDecodeType =   Zend_Json::TYPE_ARRAY)
{
    $encodedValue = (string) $encodedValue;
    if (function_exists('json_decode') && self::$useBuiltinEncoderDecoder !== true) {
        [...]
        return $decode;
    }

    #require_once 'Zend/Json/Decoder.php';
    return Zend_Json_Decoder::decode($encodedValue, $objectDecodeType);
}
```